# Explain Self Join

Tags: mysql, join

I have tried to understand self-join studying on the Internet, but couldn't find satisfactory explanation. can anybody please explain it with an example like where to use it and why to use it? would be nice if you can explain it with query.

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia's Join (SQL) page has a specific [entry about self-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Self-join), including an example.

As another example, suppose you had a Person table with columns of `Id` and `ParentId` to indicate parentage, you might do something like:

```
SELECT parent.Name, child.Name
FROM Person parent
INNER JOIN Person child ON parent.Id = child.ParentId
```

Answer (score 3):

Reasons for using a self join me be a hierarchy.

E.g.:
You have all employees in a table. Every employee has a manager. So you can link an employee with his manager.

Table emp (loyee). cols emp_id, manager, name

so you could get all employees together with the name of the manager

```
select e.name employeename, m.name managername 
from emp e, emp m where e.manager = m.emp_id
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason why you'd want to self-join is to find duplicates in your table. Say you wanted to find people with the same name in your table, you could do it like:

```
SELECT table1.name FROM people AS table1 , people AS table2 
WHERE table1.name = table2.name
AND table1.id != table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as a normal join with a copy of the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

The self-join provides the administrator with a powerful method of centralizing relational data to a single table. In fact, the self-join is performed by joining a particular table to itself.  See 
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/MySQL-Table-Joins/4/

Answer (score 0):

## SELF JOIN ?

For example we take this table
[image]

SELECT CONCAT(m.name, ', ',m.email) AS 'manager', CONCAT(e.name, ', ', e.email) AS 'reporter' FROM collage e JOIN collage m ON          m.emp_id = e.role_id;

[image]