# How do I compare values from different column and different row but same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
ID Name FatherID Birthyear

1   Bart    NULL     1756    
2   Franz   1        1796
3   Josef   2        1835    
4   Zohan   3        1887
```

Suppose I have this table, I would like to know if Zohan is the son of Bart, which can be gotten if I compare the values from the column "FatherID" with the ID of the previous rows up until I get to Bart. But how do I compare the values in the same table but of different rows and columns

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103861/explain-self-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could self join the table:

```
SELECT s.name AS son_name, f.name AS father_name
FROM   mytable s
JOIN   mytable f ON s.fatherID = f.id
-- possibly add a where clause with conditions on son/father names
```

Comment: I believe I will need to use a loop in PL/SQL to solve this but you still answered the question. Thanks!